# Modification of an algorithm for detecting cycles in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

In the following code i check if the graph contain's cycle or not and it is working 100%, but i do want to modify it so instead of printing Yes, i want it to print the first node of the repetition of the cycle. So for example if the actual graph has a cycle and the cycle is 0,1,3,5,7,0 , instead of yes i want to print 0.
Or if the cycle is 1,3,5,7,8,1 it should print 1. If anyone got idea i would appreciate it, thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

// Class for an undirected graph
class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
    list<int> *adj;    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
    bool isCyclicUtil(int v, bool visited[], int parent);
public:
    Graph(int V);   // Constructor
    void addEdge(int v, int w);   // to add an edge to graph
    bool isCyclic();   // returns true if there is a cycle
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
    adj[w].push_back(v); // Add v to w’s list.
}

// A recursive function that uses visited[] and parent to detect
// cycle in subgraph reachable from vertex v.
bool Graph::isCyclicUtil(int v, bool visited[], int parent)
{
    // Mark the current node as visited
    visited[v] = true;

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    {
        // If an adjacent is not visited, then recur for that adjacent
        if (!visited[*i])
        {
            if (isCyclicUtil(*i, visited, v))
                return true;
        }

        // If an adjacent is visited and not parent of current vertex,
        // then there is a cycle.
        else if (*i != parent)
            return true;

    }
    return false;
}

// Returns true if the graph contains a cycle, else false.
bool Graph::isCyclic()
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited and not part of recursion
    // stack
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    // Call the recursive helper function to detect cycle in different
    // DFS trees
    for (int u = 0; u < V; u++)
        if (!visited[u]) // Don't recur for u if it is already visited
            if (isCyclicUtil(u, visited, -1)){
                return true;
            }

    return false;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int res=0;
    int m, n;
    cin >> m >> n;

    Graph g1(m);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int q, r;
        cin >> q >> r;
        g1.addEdge(q, r);
    }

    g1.isCyclic()? cout << "Yes":
    cout << "No";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the beginning of a cycle? A cycle by itself does not have a beginning. In your example if 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 0 is a cycle 0 is the first elemens as is 3 or 7

Comment: I mean the first element that is repeated in that case 0 is the element that is repeated first. Or if there is a cycle 1,6,7,8,9,8 , it should print 8, i think it is clear now :)

Comment: Is this homework? What is holding you back from just printing it?

Comment: No, it's not. The first element depends on where you start the search. In your second example you could have another path leading to 9 first (instead of 8). What I want to say is that the 'first' lelement is not well-defined. Maybe you need to tell us more about 'why' you need it.

Comment: It is not a homework, just a graph problem on my college local algorithm's practice site.

Comment: @mouseepaad In answer to a question that effectively asked "what do you mean by 'first'" you just repeated 'first'.  There is no inherent meaning of "first" in this context.  You need to define it.  You might mean lowest numbered.  You might think you mean the first you encountered while searching for the cycle.  But the search is pretty arbitrary, so first encountered will not be a satisfying meaning of "first".

Comment: You algorithm does not work!  So fix it before worrying about output details.  Consider this input: 3 2 1 3 2 1. That is 3 nodes, 2 edges, no cycle, yet your code thinks there is a cycle.

Comment: I'm confused on how an undirected graph could have cycle. Do you mean an attached group of more than 2 nodes?

Comment: @kchoi I'm pretty sure "cycle" is supposed to mean two different paths from X to Y (conceptually a path from X to Y and a path from Y to X other than backtracking the path from X to Y).

Answer (score 0):

Once you find a cycle, by visiting a node you already visited, you know that this node is part of the cycle.
Then you can just do a depth first search for the node itself. Once you found it, output all the nodes on the stack.

If you want to code efficient you can find cycles that way too and then output all nodes till you reach the node where you found the cycle.

Comment: The request was to output the "first" (whatever that means) item in a cycle.  But your answer aims to output all items in a cycle, and even for that, you are either wrong (would output parents of the cycle) or missing a lot of detail.

Comment: My solution outputs all items of the cycle. there is no "first" item in a cycle. It would however not output any other elements(parents) than the elements of the cycle. If you mean in the "more efficient" approach: You do depth first search for cycles. Once you find a cycle you flag the item you are at, write it out and return something that tells your recursive function that a cycle was found and it shall output the element it is at and then return that again, ... UNLESS your stack is at the flagged node, where the cycle ended(and therefore began). then the cycle is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Find a tological order (or just serialize search order) and use hash to repeating nodes and already seen cycles. Print search start node number. Depending on your search order, your results may differ.